# Why didn't Dooku use Force lightning on the Invisible Hand?

Tags: star-wars

Why didn't Dooku use Force lightning on Anakin or Obi-Wan on his final duel on the Invisible Hand? Its his best tactic, and he used it in the first duel and all TCW duels ta boot.

Comment: Is it possible that Palpatine didn't know he could use it?  The other times Palpatine wasn't present, on the Hand he was.  If so, then it might be a secret Dooku would have liked to keep for the time he tried to overthrow Palpatine and become the master himself.  All of this is dependent on Dooku knowing that Palpatine == Sidious, of course; I'm not well-versed enough in SW lore to say if that (or any of this) was the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we saw in Dooku vs. Anakin 1, force lightning only worked on Jedi who didn't know it was coming.  A lightsaber proved an effective defense for both Obi-Wan and Mace Windu when they faced the lightning.  With no advantage of surprise Dooku used telekinesis instead, which was enough to disable Obi-Wan.